# How to call overloaded remote procedure from pqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, stored-procedures, libpqxx

How to call overloaded remote procedure from pqxx?

Procedures eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(str text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN    
    RETURN 'text';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(num integer) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN    
    RETURN 'int';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

C++ code:

```
pqxx::connection connection(/* credentials */);

std::string query_mark = "test_procedure_mark";
connection.prepare(query_mark, "SELECT foo($1);");

//first case
pqxx::work work(connection);
pqxx::result res = work.prepared(query_mark)("text").exec();
work.commit();
std::string ans = res[0][0].as(std::string(""));  //ans here "text"

//second case
pqxx::work work(connection);
pqxx::result res = work.prepared(query_mark)(1).exec();
work.commit();
std::string ans = res[0][0].as(std::string("")); //ans here "text"
```

How can i call "foo(num integer)" from c++ code? In example desired result "int" in "ans".

psql.exe output:

> SELECT foo(1); returns "int"
>
> SELECT foo("test"); returns "text"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can solve it with a single prepared statement.

You can set each parameter's treatment in libpqxx 3.1 (see [third example](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/3.1/html/Reference/a00193.html)), like:

```
connection.prepare(query_mark_text, "SELECT foo($1);")("text", pqxx::prepare::treat_string);
connection.prepare(query_mark_int,  "SELECT foo($1);")("integer");
```

But i cannot see that in the [latest docs](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00200.html).

Or, you can cast your parameteres to the desired type on PostgreSQL's side, with:

```
connection.prepare(query_mark_text, "SELECT foo($1::text);");
connection.prepare(query_mark_int,  "SELECT foo($1::int);");
```

Comment: I can't use the first example in pqxx v4.0.1

Comment: It seems (the current) `libpqxx` does not handle param types at all: http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/browser/trunk/src/connection_base.cxx#L906 -- *If paramTypes is NULL, or any particular element in the array is zero, the server assigns a data type to the parameter symbol in the same way it would do for an untyped literal string.* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html